# Scala Seq case match

Tags: scala

I have a Sequence that I would like to case match. The question that I have is quite simple:

Are the following two cases the same?

```
case x :: Nil =>
case x :: xs  =>
```

Can I instead just have

```
case Nil =>
case x :: xs  =>
```

How would the case x :: Nil be handled? Would it also match the case Nil?

Comment: Be aware that your cases (with addition of the `case x :: Nil` from the answer you got) will not work for all `Seq`, only for `List`. When you use the `Seq` factory you do get `List`, but there are many non-`List` `Seq`.

Comment: In that case, should I consider doing a toList before I pass them through the case match?

Comment: That would be safer. In fact, if the signature of the method is `Seq`, then it would be required to consider the code correct. It will be a no-op for things that are already `List`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

`case x :: Nil` matches a list with **exactly** one element.

`case x :: xs` matches a list that has **at least** one element.

`case Nil` matches an **empty** list

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!